# How to keep customized length for matpaginator?

Tags: angular, mat-pagination

I am using a `MatPaginator` with a customized length. The issue is that the customized length works just after initial loading. But after that, when I execute other API request using a search input field, and get a new result, the paginator shows the default length of the `dataSource` again. How can I keep the my defined customized length over the whole process?

The value if the customized length should be used just if it's not `0`, otherwise the default `dataSource` length should be passed/used

TS:

```
@ViewChild('usersPaginator')
public set usersPaginator(mp: MatPaginator) {
    if (this.dataSourceUsers) {
        this.dataSourceUsers.paginator = mp;
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<mat-paginator #usersPaginator [length]="usersService.customizedLength()" [pageSizeOptions]="[5,10,15]" [showFirstLastButtons]="true" />
```

P.S. `customizedLength()` is a signal holding a result of calculation which I run in the service after getting the API response.